# TPL Dataflow Batchblock Duplicate elements

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow, pipelining

My DataFlow pipeline starts with a `BatchBlock` and several Tasks are posting items into this `BatchBlock`. Now, this `BatchBlock`propagates data to the next block depending on a Timer with the help of the `TriggerBatch()` method.

In this case, you can assume that none of the batches are of the (very high) batch size provided during the creation of the `BatchBlock` i.e. each triggered batch could be of a different size.

Just before triggering the `BatchBlock` I would like to remove all duplicate items present in the batch that is about to be propagated to the next block in the pipeline. Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't add or remove items that are stored inside blocks.

However, you can add a `TransformBlock` after the `BatchBlock` that removes duplicates for the current batch and moves the batch forward. Keep in mind that it means your batches may be smaller.

Assuming equality members are implemented correctly it can look like this:

```
var transformBlock = new TransformBlock<int[], IEnumerable<int>>(_ => new HashSet<int>(_));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, after reading it I was feeling stupid as to why I couldn't think of that :) Thanks a lot!